# codeigniter sidebar

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, controller

i have a little problem that i dont know what to do with.

i have a template with

- header
- content
- sidebar
- footer

on all my page the only thing that need to change is the content, so how can i pass data to my sidebar/footer

do i need to make a controller? or do i need to make a library and load it in my template.php file?

i use this template system
http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your specific Template Library, but I do know that generally this is done by nesting views inside other views, and as long as the data is loaded into the initial view, it propagates to nested views as well.

Example without Template library

**Controller function**

```
function index() {

    $data['some_var']    = "some value";
    $data['another_var'] = "another value";

    $this->load->view('first_view',$data);
}
```

**first_view**

```
<? $this->load->view('header') ?>

<h1>Content</h1>

<? $this->load->view('sidebar') ?>
<? $this->load->view('footer') ?>
```

In this instance, the `$data` that is loaded into `first_view` propagates to `header`,`sidebar`,and `footer`.

So you can use `$some_var` or `$another_var` in any of these views.

**UPDATE**

Another way you can load data in to your views *globally* is with this function

```
$this->load-vars($data);
```

Where `$data` is your view data, this statement just before you load your template should allow all of this data to be accessed in any view loaded by the template.  While this *is* a shotgun approach, it is the suggested way to do this by [your chosen template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#writing).

Comment: @jondavidjohn its a good idea but i think its not best practice and there must be a better way :) hope there is someone else that can help me out :) But thanks a lot for the help ;)

Comment: Updated my answer after reading over your template libraries docs, you might look at them sometime ;)

Comment: @jondavidjohn But then i have to type $this->load->vars($data) in all my controllers to get it to work :/

Comment: you chose the template library, not me ;)

Comment: @jondavidjohn Do you think there is a better template :p?

Comment: if the data in your sidebar is universal to all views, you could execute `$this->load->vars($data)` in the constructor of the controller that loads your views, or even better, create a custom `MY_Controller` that loads the data in it's constructor.

Comment: i have found a idea with the template system, but i can see all the solutions is something about have the same thing in all the controller files :) so that sux :d but its fine for now.. thanks you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you will only ever change content, then there is no need to set up regions for your header, sidebar or footer - just add their contents to your main template file.

However if you will infrequently need to change the content of these regions, I would create "default" views for these regions, and load in each controller constructor, like thus:

```
$this->template->write_view('header', 'default/header');
$this->template->write_view('sidebar', 'default/sidebar');
$this->template->write_view('footer', 'default/footer');
```

You can then either extend these default region views or overwrite them on a per method basis (refer to the documentation of your library to find out how).